# Nginx, PHP and centos7 error 413-request-entity-too-large when connect to different network

Tags: php, nginx, upload, centos

My web system (Laravel) had 2 domain which company.test.hero (which can only be access by my company network) and example.com (which point to company.test.hero and can be access by public)

The problem is when I want to upload file, if I connect to my company network I can upload file without problem.

But if I connect with other network, it will give Error 413-request-entity-too-large (I try to upload file size 2.86mb).

I already setting NGINX upload limit in folder etc>nginx>nginx.conf

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

I also had set etc>php.ini upload limit.

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your NGiNX configuration file (usually `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) and add this line into the *http* section:

```
http {
  client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

Note: Don't use **MB**, use only **M** or it will not work!

Also do not forget to restart nginx:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```